# @datorama/akita showing error related to rxjs (export which is imported from is not found in rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-akita

I was using @datorama/akita to do with my project, everything is working fine until I run the command npm start
Then a lot of errors shows up with the same format as these

./node_modules/@datorama/akita/src/lib/arrayFind.js:31:9-29 - Error: export 'distinctUntilChanged' (imported as 'distinctUntilChanged') was not found in 'rxjs'

This repeated a lot of times with different exports but all from @datorama/akita.

My @datorama/akita version is 8.0.1 while my rxjs version is 6.6.0

Comment: It looks like [akita v8.0.1](https://github.com/salesforce/akita/blob/akita-8.0.1/package.json#L33) requires rxjs 7.8.

Comment: Oh, it fixed some... now I have fix some deprecated stuff... thx!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that updating rxjs to the newest version works...

Answer (score 0):

`@datorama/akita` version 8 requires `rxjs` version 7.8.0.
Updating `rxjs` solves the problem.